# MVC jquery dialog not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

When I click the delete button, the popup dialog shows and than disappears.  It does not stay

Here is the **code:**

.cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteOrder", "Order", new { id = item.OrderID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-delete"} );


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation Dialog" style="display:none">Delete this Order? Confirm </div>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".btn-delete").click(function () {
            var result;                

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });                 

        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: just a thought, instead of setting up the value and passing ,you can directly return true when user clicks yes.will that be applicable to your scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handle your anchor click and open dialog, if yes then set browser url to anchor href attribute

```js
$(".btn-delete").click(function(e) {
 var ahref = $(this)
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
       
        window.location = $(ahref).prop("href");
      },
      "No": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://example.com" class="btn-delete">delete item</a>
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
```

Comment: When I click Yes, it submits, but get                      Requested URL: /Mvc5/undefined